# peak finder for multidimensional array

Tags: matlab

I'm trying the following and is not working. Could someone help me on this?

```
A=rand(1,4,5);
peak_num=zeros(5,4);
for w=1:5
  peak_num(w,:)=peakfinder(A(1,1:4,w))
end
peak_num;
```

in this case the vector of peaks found for each w has a different size.

Thanks

Comment: What behaviour do you expect? You can not create a matrix where each row has a different number of elements.

Comment: What is ```peakfinder```? Can you provide its code, please?

Comment: here it goes: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25500-peakfinder-x0--sel--thresh--extrema--includeendpoints--interpolate-

Comment: Well, of course it has different size! you are using random data, I guess that each random set is different and has a different amount of peaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't really taken a look at the internals of the peakfinder function but if you make sure that it does not output a vector with more than 4 elements this is a workaround:

```
A=rand(1,4,5);
peak_num=zeros(5,4);
for w=1:5
    temp = peakfinder(A(1,1:4,w));
    peak_num(w, 1:length(temp) ) = temp
end
peak_num;
```

It sets the first elements to the return values and keeps the others being zero.